# showing undefined index when try to submit the form

Tags: php, forms

Every time I hit submit button after selecting an image will face the problem "**Notice: Undefined index: profile_picture in C:\wamp\www\Test\testImage.php on line 5**", and the page print the text **not selected** which must be display if image is not selected.
The index is defined, but why it is behave like this, please help with your suggestions

```
<?php
$photo = "";
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    $photo = trim(stripslashes($_POST["profile_picture"]));
    if($photo != '')
    {
        //$photo = trim(stripslashes($_POST["profile_picture"]));
        header("Location: success.php");
    }
    else{
        echo 'not selected';
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="signup_form" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" class="profile_picture" id="profile_picture" name="profile_picture"> </br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" class="submit_btn" value="sign up">
        </form>             
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also take a look at how to process file uploads [Its the manual, go figure, never would have thought of that](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Answer (score 1):

Files are not posted over `$_POST`.

They are posted with `$_FILES` array.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: wow, it's working now, thanks @Pupil